# Upload files to google drive php 401 error

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I have a problem when uploading a file to Google Drive, but I can't figure out how to do it. I can successfully retrieve my files, but can't upload them.

here's the error I have :

```
{ "error":
  { "errors":
    [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "authError", "message": "Invalid Credentials", "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ],
    "code": 401, "message": "Invalid Credentials"
   }
}
```

However I have my application registered with the drive SDK and im using the drive SDK client ID. And also the token is valid because it works when retrieving files from the drive.

Here's The code :

```
function create_file($token){

$file = file_get_contents("mynewsuper.txt");
$length = strlen($file);
$url="https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files";
$header = array(


"Host: www.googleapis.com",
"Authorization:Oauth $token");
$ch = curl_init();

$post = array(
        "file"=>"@mynewsuper.txt",
    );
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,false);
curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);


    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    echo $data;
}
```

Comment: You've not included `$token` in your code. Is that actually set in your version? Also, try doing a search for _google drive "malformed or illegal request"_, see what you get.

Comment: Actually $token is included as a parametre for my function, this is just a snippet of my function, where everything happens.

Comment: OK, though it is best to make such things clear. As it is presented, it's an undefined variable that people will pick up on `:)`.

Comment: Thank you halfer, I modified my post to not create any confusion :)